# Upgrading to liquid-fire 0.27.1 breaks velocity

Tags: ember.js, velocity.js

My app works fine with liquid-fire `0.26.x` and ember-cli `2.11.x`, when I upgrade to the latest cli version, `2.12.0`, liquid-fire `0.26.x` throws errors. The errors are removed when I upgrade liquid-fire to it's latest release, `0.27.1`.

However, although the app loads, the app is broken as my velocity animations no longer work and I receive the following error in my browser console:

`Velocity: First argument (transition.slideLeftIn) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect. Aborting.`

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: It's velocity.js you're talking about. Not velocity. You should fix the tag.

Comment: Can you post your custom animations? As you know, it's best to keep current with liquid-fire, so seems like something else is the issue